# Do professors get notified when someone in their research group sends in a publication?

Tags: publications, research-process, journals, advisor, arxiv

I am a new PhD student, and worked on something with a postdoc during my master's degree, and we will send it for publication in the upcoming few months. Even though the work was done during my master's, I was going to put in my current email address and research group information on the publication. Will my professor / supervisor be notified of this? It's not research that I have worked on here, and is something I probably will not want to work on again, but since we have the results we are going to publish them regardless. I would not mind anyone knowing of course, since it's public information anyhow, but I am just curious as to how this works. This is the first paper I will be submitting.

Comment: Be notified by whom?

Comment: Why not tell them ahead of time you are working on this?

Comment: By Arxiv or similar platforms where the work is submitted to. I have not informed because the subject matter is not relevant to my PhD.

Comment: It's relevant to your PhD progress that you're working on something else right now. This should be totally okay, though - projects in academia rarely begin and end perfectly at the transition point between jobs. You'll probably be doing some work post-PhD finishing up publications of work you did as a PhD student just like you're now finishing up your masters work. **Talk** to your advisor. Your advisor is a human scientist who you should be comfortable talking to about science. You can even talk to them about non-science sometimes! If they're too scary for that, they aren't an advisor.

Comment: It isn't like there is a large easily-accessed database of who is working for whom at the moment.

Comment: I hold it's a real mistake to be sending anything in without notifying the leader of the group the work comes from in advance.

Comment: Some research groups may have a mechanism for notifying the group of such things.  But, aside from something specifically set up and administered by the group, it is unlikely to occur.

Answer (score 4):

No, no one will *officially* notify anyone else, for no better reason than they don't know who they are and have better things to do with their time.

There is no universal database of working group members and there is no incentive for someone at arXiv or at a journal to seek out the possible associates of a submitting author and make judgments about relationships.

However, if you publish (say on arXiv) it is likely that someone will see it. It is possible that someone who sees it will know your PI and will mention the paper to them, perhaps (hopefully) in a congratulatory way. Publishing is, of course, making things public.

I doubt that you are breaking any rules or norms in your group that would make a conversation with your advisor uncomfortable. You could have that conversation. You could also send them a copy of the work more or less simultaneously with your submission. It is one way to build collaborative relationships in (not dysfunctional) working groups.

Answer (score 3):

If you include the name of your current research group in the paper, it is recommendable to inform your advisor about this. Some heads of institute may take offence if a publication is associated with the institute without their knowledge. And in some cases, departments receive funding depending on the amount of papers they publish, so they will want to count your publication if it has the department's name.

Your advisor will *normally* not be notified if you submit a paper without including them. However, it happened to me once that I submitted a single-author paper and the editor of the journal asked my advisor if they were aware of that (they were, of course). The editor and my advisor knew each other personally, which may or may not have played a role. In any case, you can never be sure.

And of course, even if your advisor is not notified directly, they may have one of those tickers that periodically sends them an email with "potentially interesting" recent papers. In this case, they may anyway get an email with your name and the title of your paper.

Comment: Many journals allow you to list the address where you did the work and a current address where you can be contacted.